# $\chi^2$ PDF from standard normal PDF

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, density-function, gamma-distribution, chi-squared

I was presented with the $\chi^2$ distribution as follows:

> Let $Z$ be a standard normal random variable $N(0, 1)$ and consider $X = Z^2$. It has the density
>
> $$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi x}}e^{-x/2} = \dfrac{(1/2)^{1/2}}{\Gamma(1/2)}e^{-x/2}x^{1/2 - 1}$$
>
> for $x > 0$. So $X = Z^2$ has the $\chi_1^2$ distribution with degree of freedom $1$ or $\text{Gamma}(1/2, 1/2)$.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution) for standard normal distribution gives the standard normal PDF as

> $${\displaystyle \varphi (x)={\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi }}}e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}x^{2}}}$$

So $X = Z^2 \Rightarrow Z = \sqrt{X}$, and, if I'm not mistaken, we get that the PDF becomes

$$f(x)  = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sqrt{x}}} e^{-x/2} = \dfrac{1}{x^{1/4} \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-x/2}$$

I don't see how one gets $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi x}}e^{-x/2}$. Am I misunderstanding something here? Or is there an error in what I was presented?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for the pdf of $X$ is incorrect. If we write $\Phi(z)$ for the CDF of the standard normal, then the CDF of $X:=Z^2$ is
$$
\begin{align}
F_X(x)&:=P(Z^2\le x)\\
&= P(-\sqrt x\le Z\le 0)+P(0\le Z\le\sqrt x)\\
&=2 P(0\le Z\le \sqrt x) \\
&=2[\Phi(\sqrt x)-\Phi(0)]
\end{align}\tag1
$$
so the PDF of $X$ is the derivative of (1), which is
$$
f(x)=\frac d{dx}F_X(x)\stackrel{(*)}=2\Phi'(\sqrt x)\frac d {dx}\sqrt x=2\varphi(\sqrt x)\frac1{2\sqrt x}=\frac1{\sqrt x}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x/2}.
$$
Step (*) is the chain rule.

Comment: Thank you. Where did the constant $2$ in (1) come from?

Comment: @DomFomello I've added more detail to the derivation. The probability that $-a\le Z\le a$ is twice the probability that $0\le Z\le a$, since $Z$ is symmetric around zero.